# Using taylor series for $\ln$

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In Reif's *Statistical and Thermal Physics*, chapter 3.6, it is said:

> If the macroscopic system $A'$ has $\Omega '(E')$ acessible states and absorbs heat $Q'=\Delta \bar{E}$, one can express the resulting change in $\ln \Omega'$ by a Taylor's expansion. Thus $$\ln\Omega '(E'+Q')-\ln\Omega '(E')=(\frac{\partial \ln\Omega '}{\partial E'})Q'+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial \ln\Omega '^2}{\partial E'^2})Q'^2 ...$$

I'm not understanding how to go from LHS to RHS through Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you rename some variables it will make more sense. Just recall that

$$
f(x + \delta x) = f(x) + \frac{{\rm d}f(x)}{{\rm d}x} \delta x + \frac{1}{2}\frac{{\rm d^2}f(x)}{{\rm d}x^2} \delta^2 x + \cdots \tag{1}
$$

Call now $x = E'$, $\delta x = Q'$, and $f(x) = \ln\Omega'(x)$. If you replace this into Eq. (1) you get

$$
\ln\Omega '(E'+Q') = \ln\Omega'(E') + \left(\frac{\partial \ln\Omega '}{\partial E'}\right)Q'+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial^2 \ln\Omega '}{\partial E'^2}\right)Q'^2 + \cdots
$$